# Deserialize a json string in specific format

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am trying to deserialize the JSON string below:

```
[{"Code1":"AA","Code2":"AB"},{"Code1":"BB","Code2":"BC"},
 {"Code1":"A1","Code2":"A12"},{"Code1":"A2","Code2":"A23"},
 {"Code1":"A4","Code2":"A45"},{"Code1":"A3","COde2":"A45"}]
```

into the following format:

```
{"Header":["Code1","Code2"], "Values":[["AA","AB"],["BB","BC"],["A1","A12"],["A2","A23"],["A4","A45"],["A3","A45"]]}
```

I am trying to deserialize using `JsonConvert.DeseriaizeObject()`. I am not able to achieve the desired format.

Comment: which language are you using to convert? C#? Please tag your question with it.

Comment: I am using C# and mvc or I am also interested to know if this can be achieved through web api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, so you have a collection of identically structured objects, and want to convert it to something akin to a CSV table (sequence of headers, then sequence of records)?

You can convert from the objects collection format to records table format using the following method:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

//other code, class declaration etc. goes here

string ObjectsToTable(string collectionJson)
{
    // reading the collection from passed JSON string
    JArray collection = JArray.Parse(collectionJson);

    // retrieving header as a list of properties from the first element
    // it is assumed all other elements have the exact same properties
    List<string> header = (collection.First as JObject).Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();

    // retrieving values as lists of strings
    // each string is corresponding to the property named in the header
    List<List<string>> values = collection.Children<JObject>().Select( o => header.Select(p => o[p].ToString()).ToList() ).ToList();

    // passing the table structure with the header and values
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Header = header, Values = values });
}
```

Comment: Sadly, I don't know much about ASP.NET MVC views; I only used Web API myself. As for doing that without Linq: I think it's possible, but overly verbose. Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use Linq for that?

Comment: Generally, in a properly configured Web API you can create HTTP response from an object, and it'll automatically serialize the object to JSON. In this case, you'd just create a HTTP response from the "new { Header = header, Values = values }" part. So, if you want to do it in Web API, I suggest looking for general tutorials about Web API, learning how to pass objects through controller methods, then applying that knowledge together with the method I provided in my answer. ;)